# Angular + FileList handling using FileReader bug

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Can someone explain why `this.imagesResults.push({src: reader.result});` throws this error : `Cannot read property 'imagesResults' of undefined`

I'm trying to convert every files from a FileList to Base64 and put the result inside the array and I don't understand why it says that ImageResults is undefined, I've tried every possible ways and even tried setting timesouts to make sure it was defined and I can't figure it out.

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ModalController} from "@ionic/angular";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-file-handler',
  templateUrl: './file-handler.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./file-handler.page.scss'],
})
export class FileHandlerPage implements AfterViewInit {

  @Input() f: FileList;
  imagesResults = [];

  constructor(private modalController: ModalController) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    [].forEach.call(this.f, this.readAndPreview);
    }

  readAndPreview(file) {

    const imageResults = [];
    // Make sure `file.name` matches our extensions criteria
    if ( /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name) ) {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.addEventListener('load',  () => {
        this.imagesResults.push({src: reader.result});
      })

      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

  }

  dismiss() {
    this.modalController.dismiss();
  }

}
```

Comment: If you intend to just preview a file as an image - use URL.createObjectURL instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is no plain JavaScript. It's Angular with Typescript. Maybe `call()` creates a closure at runtime and isolates the component.

Try it this way:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.f.forEach( file => { 
        this.readAndPreview(file);
    }
}
```